# Issue with plotting two time series in one graph

Tags: r, plot, graph, finance, stock

I have an issue with plotting two time series in one graph. I have downloaded two time series from Yahoo! Finance. Data is OK. I can plot them separately well, but when I want to plot them together to compare their dynamics, R did not create plot I needed. I used scripts from https://rpubs.com/odenipinedo/visualizing-time-series-data-in-R but it did not help. However, the plot that is shown on this website is what I need and what should be done by R.

I personally think the problem is with index, where the dates are located. As graph needs x and y, where y are time series data, x should be dates (e.g. 2022-02-20), but R did not match graphs.

```
lapply(c("quantmod", "dplyr", "tidyr", "timeSeries", "ggplot2"), require, character.only = TRUE)

tickers <- c("TSN", "^GSPC")
start_date <- "2022-02-20"

portfolioPrices <- NULL
for (Ticker in tickers) 
  portfolioPrices <- cbind(portfolioPrices,
                           getSymbols(Ticker, from = start_date, src = "yahoo", auto.assign=FALSE)[,4])

portfolioPrices <- portfolioPrices[apply(portfolioPrices,1,function(x) all(!is.na(x))),]
colnames(portfolioPrices) <- tickers
portfolioReturns <- ROC(portfolioPrices, type = "discrete")
portfolioReturns <-as.timeSeries(portfolioPrices)

plot(portfolioReturns$TSN)
lines(portfolioReturns$`^GSPC`, col = "red")
axis(side = 4, at = pretty(portfolioReturns$`^GSPC`)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lch2v.png)))

I have checked several websites and youtube videos, but nothing helped. I tried ggplot and ggseas packages, but they did not help either. The result should be similar to this screenshot:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTIwS.png)

Comment: As a start, I think this line `portfolioReturns <-as.timeSeries(portfolioPrices)` should be `portfolioReturns <-as.timeSeries(portfolioReturns)`

Comment: Two more things that you could look at.  1) The plot says prices, while you are plotting the Returns.  2) The prices of the two series have different orders of magnitude.  So plotting TSN first, will not provide the Y-axis for GSPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two plots.

1. The returns plot is simply a call to `autoplot` plus rearrange some elements, color, title, background panel;
2. the prices plot is a two y axis plot. The right hand y axis is scaled by a factor computed from the data.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(quantmod)
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

tickers <- c("TSN", "^GSPC")
start_date <- "2022-02-20"

portfolioPrices <- NULL
for (Ticker in tickers) {
  portfolioPrices <- cbind(portfolioPrices,
                           getSymbols(Ticker, from = start_date, src = "yahoo", auto.assign=FALSE)[,4])
}
head(portfolioPrices)
#>            TSN.Close GSPC.Close
#> 2022-02-22     92.44    4304.76
#> 2022-02-23     91.99    4225.50
#> 2022-02-24     90.33    4288.70
#> 2022-02-25     93.37    4384.65
#> 2022-02-28     92.66    4373.94
#> 2022-03-01     93.83    4306.26

portfolioPrices <- portfolioPrices[apply(portfolioPrices,1,function(x) all(!is.na(x))),]
colnames(portfolioPrices) <- c("TSN", "GSPC")
portfolioReturns <- ROC(portfolioPrices, type = "discrete")

autoplot(portfolioReturns, facets = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(TSN = "black", GSPC = "red")) +
  ggtitle("Stock Returns") +
  theme_bw()
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_line()`).
```

[image]

```r
Prices <- fortify(portfolioPrices)
(fac <- with(Prices, range(TSN)/range(GSPC)))
#> [1] 0.01676810 0.02124536
fac <- max(fac)

ggplot(data = Prices, aes(Index, TSN)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = "TSN")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = GSPC * fac, color = "GSPC")) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(TSN = "red", GSPC = "black")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / fac, name = "GSPC Close Prices")) +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "TSN Close Price", color = "") +
  ggtitle("Stock Price") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>